# Is the msvcr71.dll present in Windows 2012 and higher versions by default?

Tags: windows, dll

Giving some background on the problem. We have the windows zip utility packaged along with our product. This zip utility is called from one of our product scripts and is used to package some log files. One of our customers have raised an issue that when they run our script, which invokes zip.exe, they get this pop up--"The program can't start because MSVCR71.dll is missing from your computer". I examined the zip.exe in dependency walker tool, and sure enough, I could see the dependency to msvcr71.dll. The customer told that they can overcome this by manually placing the MSVCR71.dll file in the path C:\Windows\SysWOW64 or installing Windows 7 redists.

However, I created a new Windows 2012 VM, did-not install any additional software, and I could see msvcr71.dll in the path C:\Windows\SysWOW64  and zip.exe runs successfully without complaining about missing dll. So wanted to check if msvcr71.dll  is available by default or not?

Comment: The file is part of the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable, do you have a later version of this than your client? Have they installed the latest version of Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable?

Comment: *'71* is [Visual C++ 2003](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#History) (which [interestingly](https://web.archive.org/web/20110225145354/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326922) was also the last version before they started to ship system-wide redists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable is not present by default, and needs to
be installed. This may include `msvcr*.dll`, but also `msvcm*.dll` and `msvcp*.dll`,
depending on the application.
It may sometimes be installed on a client computer by other applications,
but you cannot depend on its presence or on the version that will be installed.

To avoid such dependencies, and since clients will not always agree to install
additional packages to your own, the usual practice is to include the used
DLLs in the installation folder of the application.
This is completely legal, as this Microsoft software is "Redistributable".